# None of the action buttons are showing up on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am following the guild on developer.android.com and have made it to the part to adding action button to the bar. None of them, however, are wanting to show up. I have looked through the code, did research, and even redid the whole project just the make sure I was following everything right. Nothing I do seems to work so I thought I would put it here and let a fresh (and more experience) set of eyes look at it and let me where I am going wrong.

main_activity_actions.xml

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:myfirstapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          myfirstapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          myfirstapp:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);
        setContentView(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)  {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                //openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                //openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" > 
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

screenshot
[image]

Comment: It is showing, but not on actionbar? Right?

Comment: They are not showing up at all, I will add a screen shot to show

Comment: which actionbar are you using?

Comment: if you are using actionbarsherlock then instead of menuinflater() use getSupportMenuInflater().

Comment: I am not using actionbarsherlock.

Comment: What is the lower android level?

Comment: I just want to know the "Menu" import at the top.

Comment: These are all my imports:                                       import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`inside

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)  {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and also add `return true` instead of `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`

Comment: Tried that and I'm still getting nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return true;
}
```

try this. Its working for me.

Comment: Tried this as well, still no luck.